# Domain has SPF Record, One Email Account Always Goes to Junk

Tags: email-server, domain, spf, txt-record

We've got a domain and email with 1&1 hosting. The domain has an SPF text record. We've got 8 email accounts, and all but one of them can send emails to external addresses without them going to the recipient's junk folder.

But one of our accounts - which is set up exactly the same as the others - consistently gets all his messages delivered to the recipient's junk folders. All 8 of us have been sending to the same recipient.

I'm trying to think what could cause this behavior - why is just that one account affected? Can anyone give me any pointers? Why is this account - which is brand new - being treated differently.

Not even sure what to google at the moment, so even a lmgtfy link would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of reasons why emails are flagged as SPAM.

Since you are experiencing this with one account, I suggest to make the free tests that are available on the web, like [Glockapps](https://glockapps.com/spam-testing/) or [mailtester](http://www.mail-tester.com/) which can point to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Glockapps says everything is fine for the test inboxes it uses, but we still get the same problem when sending the email to a real recipient which is odd, but I haven't used these tools before so thanks for the info, it gives me something to work with.

Comment: A colleague suggested it was the individual's name, and while there were no swear words in it (was just joe.<surname>@blahblah.co.uk), creating a new account in exactly the same way but as joseph.<surname>@blahblah.co.uk seems to have resolved the issue. Not 100% convinced that is the real cause but that's all I did in the end.